Help with solving a probability question using a combinatorial approach
I got confused when solving a conditional probabilty question from the book "Introduction to Probability" by Dimitri and Tsitsiklis.
Question is as follows:
A Class consists of 4 graduate and 12 undergraduate students is randomly divided into 4 groups of 4. What is the probability that each includes a graduate student?
I understand the book's conditional probability approach to solution (also discussed in Trouble understanding conditional probability question), which is given as:
Solution: conditional probability approach solution
What I need help is the combinatorial way to do this problem using multinomial theorem. It is probably longer but can someone solve it this way please.

I tried doing it the following way but the answer is not correct:
given that each group has 4 available spots, there will be a total of 16 spots to fill. Then we start filling them one by one where each group would get only 1 grad student.
For the first group's first spot let's place a grad student and then fill the remaining spaces with ugrad students. Since this can have different orderings such as (grad, ugrad, ugrad, ugrad), (ugrad, grad, ugrad, ugrad), (ugrad, ugrad, grad, ugrad), and (ugrad, ugrad, ugrad, grad) we need to multiply by 4 to handle all of the 4 different orderings where the first group gets only 1 grad student. This is given by: (4/16) * (12/15) * (11/14) * (10/13) * 4
Then we try to fill the second group's 4 spots with only 1 grad student again and take into consideration the 4 different available orderings. This yields: (3/12) * (9/11) * (8/10) * (7/9) * 4
Then with the same logic we try to place only 1 grad student to the third group. Which yields: (2/8) * (6/7) * (5/6) * (4/5) * 4
Then the last group automatically has 1 grad student and 3 ugrad students.
Putting all of the equations above together we obtain the following:
(4/16) * (12/15) * (11/14) * (10/13) * 4 * (3/12) * (9/11) * (8/10) * (7/9) * 4 * (2/8) * (6/7) * (5/6) * (4/5) * 4 = wrong answer
Thank you very much for your help.

This is hard to read.  As far as I can sort out, the given proof is combinatorial so what more do you want?  Note that writing things like $P(A_3)=1215\times 814\times 413$ is just gibberish.

@lulu thank you for the feedback. In light of your feedback I provided the solution as an image. What I want is a solution which takes an approach where students are placed slot by slot. The current provided solution tries to make sure that given the previous grad students are not in the same group, the next grad to be placed will be in another group too. The approach I am looking for looks more like this: the probability that we will choose a grad student for the first slot is 4/16, then the probability that the next slot will be not occupied by a grad student is 12/15 e.t.c.

The given proof is so simple...Just work out the probability that the first group has a graduate student and now you are down to a smaller problem

@lulu I agree that it is simpler but I am trying to derive the other solution to have a better understanding myself, and also to appreaciate the simplicity of this solution better.

Well, I can't sort out what it is you are after so I suggest working the same problem for a smaller collection.  Presumably your idea makes sense for smaller collections, yes?  So work one of them out and add it to your post.  Try it for four balls, two white two black, what's the probability that the first two and the last two each contain one of each color?  Simplest version of the question.

@lulu, the already available question assigns the remainign grad students to the four available groups. Instead of this, I am trying to assign students one by one to the remaining spots for all of the 16 available spots. Something like, for the first group the probability that only the first spot has a grad student would be (4/16) * (12/15) * (11/14) * (10/13), then we can multiply this by 4 since there are 4 different orderings of it available (grad, ugrad, ugrad, ugrad). Then for the second group to have one of the remaining grad student we will have (3/12) * (9/11) * (8/10) * (7/9) ...

Again, edit your post to work a simpler example along the lines you prefer.  If you already have the computation you like, then what's the question?

I know this is redundant, but just to stress:  this problem is a triviality.  There are $\binom {16}4$ ways to place the grads without restriction.  There are $4$ ways to put one of them in the first four, and $4$ ways for the next $4$ and so.  So $4^4$ "good" arrangements.  Thus the answer is the ratio $4^4\big / \binom {16}4$.

@lulu I have edited my post with the wrong answer I obtain while trying to solve it the way I am trying to.  I couldn't do it for a trivial case since my solution does not work but I included my approach for the given problem. I hope this helps.

So, please try a simpler example.  That should make it clear what the problem is.

If you want a multinomial solution, you can  write
$$Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom 4{1,1,1,1} \dbinom{12}{3,3,3,3}}{\dbinom{16}{4,4,4,4}}$$
However, isn't it  simpler to just forget  about the non-graduates, and place the graduates one by one in different groups.
The first can go anywhere, and the rest can go turn by turn into valid  slots, thus
$$Pr = \frac{12}{15}\frac{8}{14}\frac{4}{13}$$
The non-graduates fit automatically in the $12$ remaining slots
That is what the book was trying to do in a more formal way using the concept of conditional probability
